# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded with flipster

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to jquery and i get the chrome error:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

With the following locations:

- q@jquery.js:2
- replace@(program):174
- m.extend.camelCase@jquery.js:2
- m.extend.style@jquery.js:4
- (anonymous function)@jquery.js:4
- m.access@jquery.js:4
- m.fn.extend.css@jquery.js:4
- (anonymous function)@jquery.flipster.min.js:2
- m.extend.each@jquery.js:2
- m.fn.m.each@jquery.js:2

The only JS i have at the moment is this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".my-flipster").flipster();

    if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        $(".rolf-b").show();
        $(".rolf-l").show();
        $(".rolf-d").show();
        $(".rolf-c").show();
    } else {
        $(".rolf-b").hide();
        $(".rolf-l").hide();
        $(".rolf-d").hide();
    }

    $(".click-rolf-b").click(function () {
        $(".rolf-l").hide();
        $(".rolf-c").hide();
        $(".rolf-d").hide();
        $(".rolf-b").show();

    });

    $(".click-rolf-c").click(function () {
        $(".rolf-l").hide();
        $(".rolf-b").hide();
        $(".rolf-d").hide();
        $(".rolf-c").show();

    });
    $(".click-rolf-d").click(function () {
        $(".rolf-l").hide();
        $(".rolf-b").hide();
        $(".rolf-c").hide();
        $(".rolf-d").show();

    });
    $(".click-rolf-l").click(function () {
        $(".rolf-d").hide();
        $(".rolf-b").hide();
        $(".rolf-c").hide();
        $(".rolf-l").show();

    });


});
```

This is located in script.js

I've included my JS files like this:

```
</div>
    <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.flipster.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

I use this flipster JS only on one page, but the error is everywhere. Has it really something to do with Flipster? Flipster is a coverflow plugin found here: https://github.com/drien/jquery-flipster

Comment: `call stack size exceeded` = infinite loop or recursion.

Comment: Ok,but do you know where this loop could be or how i've made it? I didn't changed jQuery at all.

Comment: @olivier did you manage to find a solution for this? we are trying to put 2 carousels (desktop & mobile) on the same page and facing the same issue.

Comment: Hi Mohamed, I'm afraid i don't remember. But if you have luck, you will find the JS we used on the Page at http://www.lemag-ag.ch/ueber-uns Just view the source.